# mariadb, group by column names, hour/dayofthemonth

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mariadb, sql-order-by

I really don't know much SQL, so I don't know quite well what I should use to achieve the following, which I understand should definitely be doable, I know I'm missing some basic SQL concepts here.

data:

| date | hostname | dbfinds | dbreads | dbupdates | dbinserts | dbdeletes | dbrollbacks | dbcommits | dbothers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| datetime | varchar | int | int | int | int | int | int | int | int |

it's pretty selfexplanatory but the values in the rows are the sum of those kind of commands that have been sent to the db (adabas in this case) on a particular date, we keep months of data.

I need to create two heatmap in a software (metabase), it can make a query to a db and display the result in various format, including table format, it can then apply a conditional formatting to the values, so I can get color coding according to ranges and hence a heatmap.
the db holding this data being queried by metabase is mariadb (10.5).

I've already made such queries and obtained the result I needed.
In this case I need to obtain a table that looks like this

| days | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | ... | 31 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dbfinds | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 | value6 | ... | value31 |
| dbreads | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 | value6 | ... | value31 |

where values are the sum of all the find,read,etc. commands processed in that day of the month

I also need to build a similar table with hour of the day

| hours | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | ... | 24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dbfinds | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 | value6 | ... | value24 |
| dbreads | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 | value6 | ... | value24 |

this query produces a similar result where the results are grouped by the hour of the day and the day of the week:

those brackets in the where clause are a metabase specific notation, it's so that a filter on the page where it's being displayed will actually provide the value of {{Date}}

```
SELECT hour(adabas.date) AS "Hour", DAYNAME(adabas.date) AS "Days", (SUM(dbfind)+SUM(dbread)+SUM(dbupdates)+SUM(dbinserts)+SUM(dbdeletes)+SUM(dbrollbacks)+SUM(dbcommits)+SUM(dbothers)) AS "count"
FROM adabas WHERE {{Date}}
GROUP BY hour(adabas.date), DAYNAME(adabas.date)
ORDER BY WEEKDAY(adabas.date), hour(adabas.date) ASC
```

so it looks like this:

| days | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| monday | value1 | value2 | value3 | ... | value24 |
| tuesday | value1 | value2 | value3 | ... | value24 |

In order to group by my column names I think I need a join, or maybe a union, from a slighlty different select, something like this (the following is not working, there's an error in the query)

```
( SELECT DAYNAME(adabas.date) AS "Days", (SUM(dbfind)+SUM(dbread)+SUM(dbupdates)+SUM(dbinserts)+SUM(dbdeletes)+SUM(dbrollbacks)+SUM(dbcommits)+SUM(dbothers)) AS "count"
FROM adabas WHERE {{Date}} )
union
( SELECT column_name as "Command"
FROM information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'adabas' )

GROUP BY "Command", hour(adabas.date), DAYNAME(adabas.date)
ORDER BY "Command"
```

Comment: Your source data structure is extremely poor. I'd recommend to normalize it to `date` - `hostname` - `type` (foreign key to type names table - dbfinds, dbreads, ..) - `value` (int).

Comment: You need in PIVOT. You may use either conditional aggregation (its query text will be too long) or stored procedure with dynamic SQL.

Comment: we didn't gave any thought to the data structure really, that's exactly what I get in a csv from the program that export that data from the adabas db, your suggestion seems a lot more valid, thanks for pointing me out to the correct SQL tool (PIVOT)